# In Symfony2, how to use Multiple Routes in Default Controller

Tags: symfony

I've been trying to map multiple routes to the default controller, and it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I'm using annotations in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index_controller");
 * @Template("SeoSlinkyBundle:Default:index.html.twig");
 */
 public indexAction() {}
```

but I want to do this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index_controller");
 * @Route("/{timeoption}", name="index_controller");
 * @Template("SeoSlinkyBundle:Default:index.html.twig");
 */
 public indexAction($timeoption = "today") {
   echo $today;
   exit;
 }
```

That actually works, and if I go to:

`http://myapp/hello`

The controller echoes "hello"

but if I go to

`http://myapp/`

The controller should echo "today"

but instead I'm getting this error:

Cannot import resource "/usr/share/www/myapp/src/MyAppBundle/Controller/" from "/usr/share/www/myapp/app/config/routing.yml".

These are the contents of routing.yml

```
my_app:
    resource: "@MyAppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
imag_ldap:
    resource: "@IMAGLdapBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be because you have **2 routes with the same name which is wrong**.

You should try :

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index_controller");
 * @Route("/{timeoption}", name="index_controller_timeoption");
 * @Template("SeoSlinkyBundle:Default:index.html.twig");
 */
 public indexAction($timeoption = "today") 
 {
     echo $today;
     exit;
 }
```

Comment: exactly my suggestion - you were faster :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense!! I would never have thought of that, it's so simple that makes me feel kind of dumb.